# Adding dynamic properties to object only if the name is defined

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

i have a function like this:

```
const getKeysAs = (key1, key2) => {
    return {
        [key1]: state.key1,
        [key2]: state.key2
    }
}
```

So if state.key1 is 'a' and state.key2 is 'b', calling `getKyesAs('one', 'two')` would return

```
{
  one: 'a',
  two: 'b'
}
```

Now, if one of the argument is `undefined`, is there a way to not include it in the returned object ?

Comment: `const o = {}; if (key1) o[key1] = ...;`…?

Comment: Do you actually mean `state[key1]`?

Answer (score 1):

Use [Object.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign).

```
const getKeysAs = (key1, key2) => {
    return Object.assign({}, key1 && {[key1]: state[key1]}, key2 && {[key2]: state[key2]});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can Conditionally add properties to an Object with [object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

```
const obj = {
    ...(key1 && { [key1]: state[key1] }),
    ...(key2 && { [key2]: state[key2] })
};
```

If some of the args function is `undefined`, `null` or `0` (falsy values) then it will no be added to the object.

Comment: Object destructuring refers getting values **out** of an object. You are doing the opposite. This syntax is called *object spread*.

Answer (score 1):

There is a very scalable way to do it:

```js
const state= {
  a: "hello",

}
function getKeysAs (keys) {
return [...arguments].reduce((acc, cur)=> {
  const newValue = state[cur] && {[cur]: state[cur]}
  return {...acc, ...newValue}
}, {}) 
}

console.log(getKeysAs("a", "b"))
```

This way, you can pass as much keys as you need without worrying about scalability & undefined values.

Comment: Assuming the OP actually means to do `state[key1]`, not `state.key1` as in their example.

Comment: Yes indeed. I would suggest him to keep a consistent state then. It will make the code easier to understand and more scalable.

Comment: I agree if you mean that the state should be an array, not an object. But if you didn't mean that then state[key1] and state.key1 are both the same, right ? @DoneDeal0

Comment: In my example, the state is still an object. state[value] means state.nameOfMyDynamicValue and state.value means state.value. So by state[cur], you actually fetch state.nameOfCurrentKey. arguments is a native way to fetch all parameters from a function, it's not commonly used, so it looks fancy lol. Here arguments would be ["a", "b"]. so first reduce round => "a": state.a, then "b": state.b.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you actually mean to do `state[key1]`, not `state.key1`, here is a solution that doesn't create superfluous objects:

```
const getKeysAs = (...keys) => {
  const result = {};
  for (const key of keys) {
    if (key != null) {
      result[key] = state[key];
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```